# SharedPreferences.getBoolean throwing ridiculous exception

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having a really frustrating problem with SharedPreference.getBoolean in android. See the following snippet:

```
Map<String, ?> all = preferences.getAll();

Object x = all.get("EnableMedia");

boolean v = preferences.getBoolean("EnableMedia", (Boolean) null);
```

I can see in the debugger that 'x' is a Boolean and it is true.

Yet, if I execute the next line, preferences.getBoolean, it throws an exception. What gives?!

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the exception... please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You can't set a primitive type (boolean) to null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this call:

```
preferences.getBoolean("EnableMedia", (Boolean) null);
```

Now look at the signature of `getBoolean`:

```
public abstract boolean getBoolean (String key, boolean defValue)
```

Note that it's a `boolean` value, not a `Boolean` value. So what's actually happening is your code is something like this:

```
Boolean tmp = null;
preferences.getBoolean("EnableMedia", tmp.booleanValue());
```

That will throw a `NullPointerException`, as you're calling a method on a null reference.

You need to pass in a valid `boolean` value, e.g.

```
preferences.getBoolean("EnableMedia", true);
```

Comment: You are right of course. This resolved that problem. However, this class still seems completely busted to me. It is always returning the value I pass for defValue, even though there is clearly an entry in the Map that is different. I'm seeing the same behavior for integers in the Map as well.

Comment: @dsharlet: Given your previous analysis of a perfectly sensible exception as "ridiculous" I'm not particularly inclined to trust your sense of diagnostics. What happens if you call `contains`?

Comment: FYI, that Boolean cast was generated automatically by Eclipse, so I wouldn't say it was a question wildly out of left field. Anyways, I think I've resolved this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dsharlet: But only after you'd tried passing in null? I can't imagine it would just have suggested a null value by itself. (And next time, *please* give the details of the exception you're getting right from the start.)

Comment: Well, while on that topic, part of the reason I was getting *so* frustrated is that it is very difficult to actually see what exceptions are thrown in Eclipse and from where. I probably would have been able to figure out what was going on in this case if Eclipse behaved more like Visual Studio/C++, where you break where the exception is *thrown*, not where its caught. The 'Java Exception Breakpoint' feature appears to not work either (always breaks at the bottom of the call stack).

Comment: @dsharlet: Did printing out the stack trace of the exception not give you all the information you needed? (That stack trace is what I'd expect to see in the question.) I admit I haven't done any Java development, but normally I don't have any problem debugging exceptions in Eclipse...